# Handlebars.js - dynamically generated link in attached partial template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to add a partial template to my main template, and in this example below everything works great.

But, is it possible to change name of that folder "1-1" for the one dynamically generated? You know something like that doesn't work {{>templates_animals_{{id}}_africa}}, 
and I understand why, but how to do it differently.
I need that name of this folder was inserted into the template from js

HELP

**path:** templates/animals/general.hbs

```
   {{#animals}}
    <div>
      {{>templates_animals_1-1_africa}}
    </div>
   {{/animals}}
```

**path for partial template:** templates/animals/1-1/africa.hbs

Comment: I dont think its possible 
https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/189
https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/244

Comment: eh ok :(:( , thank You for links

Comment: swag has a modified partial helper. Might be what you need http://elving.github.io/swag/